# Do automorphisms of quotient fields preserve the underlying ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is an integral domain. Let $\gamma: \mathrm{Frac}(R) \rightarrow \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ be an automorphism of the quotient field. Is it true that $\gamma(R) = R?$ I don't think that this is true in general, but I cannot think of any examples. Are there examples for which this is not true?

Comment: In many cases together with some counter-examples what you need is for $\sigma\in Aut(Frac(R))$ sending $S \to S$ what does it imply for the integral closure and normal closure of $S$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a field automorphism $\gamma: \text{Frac}(R)\to\text{Frac}(R)$ need not map $R$ to $R$. Take $R = \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\gamma: \mathbb{Q}(x) \to \mathbb{Q}(x)$ defined by preserving $\mathbb{Q}$ and by $\gamma(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: This is a counterexample, or an example where it is not true. $R$ is an integral domain, $\gamma$ is a field automorphism $\text{Frac}(R)\to\text{Frac}(R)$ with $\gamma(R) \ne R$. This is because $x$ is not invertible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: Thanks. The OP ends their question with "Are there examples for which this is not true?" And you start your answer by saying "No." That's what confused me. (+1)

Comment: No worries. I stopped reading at "Is it true that $\gamma(R) = R$?"